# Five responsive columns in a row with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I want to create a row which has 5 responsive columns which have equal padding from top to bottom and from the sides, but can't find the best solution how to achieve it with bootstrap.

Current html:

```
  <div class="row five-col-row">
    <div class="col col-md-2 mx-2">
      <h6>Sources</h6>
      <span>{{ allStats.sources }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 mx-2">
      <h6>Installs</h6>
      <span>{{ allStats.installs }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 mx-2">
      <h6>Conversions</h6>
      <span>{{ allStats.conversions }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 mx-2">
      <h6>Amount</h6>
      <span>{{ allStats.conversion_amount }}$</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 mx-2">
      <h6>Churn rate</h6>
      <span>{{ allStats.churn_rate }}%</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to create a responsive five column grid with Bootstrap?

The result I want to achieve is:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `col-md-2` with 5 columns will give extra spacing for 2 col at the end. Is there an reason for not using `col` for every break points?

Comment: I don't need extra space at the end.
Want to achieve the result which is provided in the image.

Answer (score 0):

#### Do not use margin-x on `.col-*` elements.

1. Set your custom padding-x on `.col-*`
2. Set padding-y on `row.` It should be two times padding-x of `.col-*`. For instance, if you set a 10px padding-x on columns, the padding-y of  row should be 20px becuase there is 20px space between the columns.
3. Wrap the content of the `.col-*` elements in a `div` and apply all the style to this element instead of the column.

```css
div.col div {
  border: 1px solid #000; 
  height: 200px;  
}

.py-1rem {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-1rem">
    <div class="col col-md-2 px-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 px-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 px-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 px-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-2 px-2">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort, but you're provided solution is not what am I looking for.
Have you looked at the image i provided for the result i want to achieve?
With your solution is all kinds of problems.

Comment: @ViktorasssIT I have done so. Could you explain what the problem is?